# how can i do validations inside a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

ok first this may be a foolish idea i tried to validate a name inside a thread  so i can undo what user has done if there is a digit this the code i wrote inside the thread's run method

```
  if(!jTextField1.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        for(int s=0;s<jTextField1.getText().length();s++)
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(jTextField1.getText().charAt(jTextField1.getText().length()-1)))
            {
                jTextField1.setText(new StringBuilder(jTextField1.getText()).deleteCharAt(jTextField1.getText().length()-1).toString() );
                showMessageDialog(null, "you cant add digts for names");
                jTextField1.setCaretPosition(jTextField1.getText().length());
            }
        }

    }
```

but this give some times exceptions some times this work though

1. StringIndexoutofBounds
2. null pointer 
   so what is the reson for this i did some other validations also inside this thread those validations are also some times work some time doesn't work i dont know the problem..

this is the id card validation i did..some time even though i enter a number it recognize it as a char and delete that number..plz help..

note :: this id card part some times work perfectly as i want only some time it doesnt work..is this because of the thread

```
 int y=-1;
    if(!jTextField4.getText().equals(""))
    {
        if(jTextField4.getText().endsWith("v"))
        {




            if(jTextField4.getText().length()<11)
            {
                jLabel11.setText(Integer.toString(10-jTextField4.getText().length()));
                for(int x=0;x<jTextField4.getText().length()-1;x++)//testing if there are any letters in the middle
                {

                    if(!Character.isDigit(jTextField4.getText().charAt(x)))
                    {
                            y=x;
                    }

                    if(y!=-1)
                    {
                        showMessageDialog(null,jTextField4.getText().charAt(x) );
                        jTextField4.setText(new StringBuilder(jTextField4.getText()).deleteCharAt(y).toString());
                        jTextField4.setCaretPosition(x);
                        showMessageDialog(null, "this should be a number");
                    }

                        y=-1;
                }





            }
            else 
            {
                jTextField4.setText(new StringBuilder(jTextField4.getText()).deleteCharAt(jTextField4.getText().length()-2).toString());
                showMessageDialog(null, "no more than 10 chars");
                jTextField4.setCaretPosition(jTextField4.getDocument().getLength()-1);

            }

        }
        else if(!jTextField4.getText().endsWith("v"))
        {
            showMessageDialog(null, "it should be ended with v");
            jTextField4.setText(jTextField4.getText()+"v");
            jTextField4.setCaretPosition(jTextField4.getDocument().getLength()-1);
        }    



    }
```

Comment: You added a second question on id cards as I was answering.  I suggest you put the part on id cards in its own separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are running this in a separate thread, the contents of jTextField1.getText() can change while this code is executed.  For example, the user might delete what's in the text field after you got the string's length but before you access the character at that position, resulting in the index out of bounds exception.

One solution would be to get the string out of the text field only once, just before this block of code, so that you are consistently working with the same string, even though the string might become outdated while your code is executing.  Your setCaretPosition() call might still throw an exception, though.  Another possibility would be to catch the index out of bounds exception, take that as a signal that the input field has been changed, and do the whole thing over again.